# Apache POI textbox looks different from excel textbox

Tags: java, textbox, apache-poi, richtextbox

[image: POI textbox vs Excel textbox]

I want to make a textbox which looks like the one on the right in the image shown above.
I tried following the documentation and wrote the following code.

```
public void TestXSSFPatriarch(String fileName, String richText) {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("hssf");
    XSSFDrawing xssfDrawing = (XSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFTextBox xssfTextBox = xssfDrawing.createTextbox(
            new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 25, 50, (short) 0, 0, (short) 25, 50));
    xssfTextBox.setText(new XSSFRichTextString(richText));

    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        System.out.println("Success");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code outputs the textbox which is shown on the left in the above image.
Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a different methods provided by the XSSFTextBox. I found an option named `setFillColor`

```
public void TestXSSFPatriarch(String fileName, String richText) {
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("hssf");
    XSSFDrawing xssfDrawing = (XSSFDrawing) sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFTextBox xssfTextBox = xssfDrawing.createTextbox(
            new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 25, 50, (short) 0, 0, (short) 25, 50));
    xssfTextBox.setText(new XSSFRichTextString(richText));

    xssfTextBox.setFillColor(255, 255, 255); // Adding the following line solved the problem
    
    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        System.out.println("Success");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```